# How do I get to calling a method from dependencies.rb after calling a method from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, activesupport

In order to find out more about how Ransack (a Gem) works I started debugging it, which brings me to the console with this prompt:

```
   28:   def index
   29:     debugger
=> 30:     @search = ControlCenter.ransack(params[:q])
```

I wanna go deeper, so I type

```
(byebug) step
```

which gives me this output:

```
[197, 206] in /Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@xxx/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb

   201:       def const_missing(const_name)
=> 202:         from_mod = anonymous? ? guess_for_anonymous(const_name) : self
   203:         Dependencies.load_missing_constant(from_mod, const_name)
   204:       end
```

Looking at the ransack method:

```
def ransack(params = {}, options = {})
  Search.new(self, params, options)
end
```

I just can't make sense of what's going on here. Aren't there calls in between? How am I ending up with ActiveSupport::Dependencies? Am I not following every call with `step`?

Comment: Thats rails autoloading Ransack::Search by overriding `const_missing`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: Thanks, just the info I wanted! If you write it as an answer I will accept.